# EF Hashset collection - Overriding Equals and GetHashCode

Tags: entity-framework

I have a many to many relationship with a join table in EF.

I have seem some suggestions in other questions to use a `Hashset` collection type for a many to many relationship and override Equals() and GetHashCode().

**Why should I use Hashset?**

**How do I override these methods and what does this accomplish?**

```
public class ChartQuery
{
    public int ChartQueryId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserChartQuery> Users { get; set; }
   ...more...
}

public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserChartQuery> SavedChartQueries { get; set; }
    ...more...
}

public class UserChartQuery
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int ChartQueryId { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual ChartQuery ChartQuery { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why should I use Hashset?**

You shouldn't.  The uniqueness of a many-to-many row will be enforced at the database level so long as it's mapped properly.  There is little to no benefit in enforcing it at the application level.

**How do I override these methods and what does this accomplish?**

Many-to-many relationships in Entity Framework don't have a distinct entity to represent the relationship, so there's no entity to override `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` on.

You *could* define an entity to satisfy the many-to-many relationship, but this is somewhat contrived and ugly from an object model point-of-view.  If you were to do this, you would override `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` with equality being defined as the participating keys being equal to each other, and the hash code would be a unique combination of the participating keys.

**Update**

Using your example with an entity representing the many-to-many relationship, this is how you would implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode` so that it could be properly used within a HashSet:

```
public class UserChartQuery
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int ChartQueryId { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual ChartQuery ChartQuery { get; set; }

        protected bool Equals(UserChartQuery other)
    {
        return UserId == other.UserId && ChartQueryId == other.ChartQueryId;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((UserChartQuery) obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return (UserId*397) ^ ChartQueryId;
        }
    }
}
```

As stated above, I recommend using the more natural and built-in way to do a many-to-many relationship in EF:

```
public class ChartQuery
{
    public int ChartQueryId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
   ...more...
}

public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ChartQuery> SavedChartQueries { get; set; }
    ...more...
}
```

In your mapping, you would then define the many-to-many relationship as such (in the DbContext OnModelCreating override):

```
builder.Entity<ChartQuery>()
    .HasMany(cq => ucq.Users)
    .WithMany(u => u.SavedChartQueries);
```

In either case, I really think that using a HashSet is unnecessary.  Even with the entity to satisfy the many-to-many relationship, the database will enforce uniqueness of the composite key.

Comment: Thanks for the response. "You could define an entity to satisfy the many-to-many relationship". Isn't that what I did using the `UserChartQuery` entity representing a join table? If that's the case I'm looking for a code example how to override these methods as I was unable to find one. If on the other hand you are suggesting me to use a different mapping without a join-table then please show me how to configure such a map because I was struggling with that for a while until I got what I wanted with a join table.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what you did with UserChartQuery.  Sorry I didn't notice that the first time around.  I've updated the answer.  Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: Thank you for the update, bounty it yours. As a last note, can you think of any benefit `at all` of enforcing uniqueness at the application level?

Comment: The benefit I see is that you won't get an exception when trying to persist two `UserChartQuery` objects with identical keys after being added to either the `SavedChartQueries` or `Users` collection.  Using a HashSet, it wouldn't be possible for duplicates to exist in the collection.  Doing so comes at the expense of declaring the collections as `HashSet` as opposed to `ICollection`, which in turn breaks proxy generation in entity framework.  A workaround would be to create an IEqualityComparer for `UserChartQuery` and use LINQ's `Distinct` method to clear out any dupes.

Comment: I like the comment from w. brian ... "Using a HashSet, it wouldn't be possible for duplicates to exist in the collection" is one of the primary reasons EF will implement hashsets in this manner natively.  For instance, if you do db first design, EF will generate classes with Hashset implementations.  Yes, it comes at a cost, though.